# How can I cache customerror page using outputcache

Tags: asp.net, caching, asp.net-mvc-5, memcached

How can I cache customerror page using outputcache?

to customize the error page:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/customerror/notfound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="/customerror/servererror" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

customerrorcontroller:

```
public class CustomErrorController
{

    [OutputCache(Duration = duration, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, VaryByHeader = "Host", VaryByParam = "None")]
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        return this.View("NotFound", this.Build());
    }

    private TestModel Build()
    {
        var model = new TestModel
                        {
                            Header = GetSiteHeaderContent(SiteId),
                            Footer = GetSiteFooterContent(SiteId),
                            Navigations = GetNavigations(),
                            SecondaryNavigations = GetSecondaryNavigation()
                        };
        return model;
    }
}
```

the problem is that the action is never cached, although I am using output cache in many places and is working fine.

Note: I am using Memcached.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Possible way could be to redirect to another action and cache it, like

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return RedirectToAction("NotFound");
}

[OutputCache]
public ActionResult NotFound()
{
    return this.View("NotFound", this.Build());
}

private TestModel Build()
{
    var model = new TestModel
                    {
                        Header = GetSiteHeaderContent(SiteId),
                        Footer = GetSiteFooterContent(SiteId),
                        Navigations = GetNavigations(),
                        SecondaryNavigations = GetSecondaryNavigation()
                    };
    return model;
}
```

Comment: but if you use the redirectToAction then the  Response.StatusCode is changing from 404. And this is not a good practice. You returning a non valid status code for a url which should return the 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

This is because ASP.NET Output caching only functions when requests respond with a 200 Status code.

Also see [ASP.NET MVC OutputCache for HTTP 503 status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124861/asp-net-mvc-outputcache-for-http-503-status-code) which had a similar problem with 503 responses.